# Expresso Store with PHP7

Tags: expresso-store, php7

I have a client running Expresso Store 2.5.1 with EE 2.10.1. I have to upgrade the server and need to know if Store 2.5.1 will run on PHP 7.1.

Since Store has not been updated to run under EE 3.x, I'm kinda stuck between a rock and a hard place with upgrading.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if you can hold off, but I do believe they are working on it according to this: http://www.devdemon.com/blog/expressionengine-3.0-porting

Comment: They've been working on it for quite a long time. Can't really wait with no signs of it being released.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm with Vector; we own Store)

We're very close to releasing Store for EE3, with full PHP 7 support. You can sign up to be part of our beta test here: https://goo.gl/forms/6p2W9Fwy8fTeQ3fE2

I know it's been "in progress" for a long time, but much of that was under the previous owners. Our 1 priority post-acquisition has been getting it EE3 compatible and we're extremely close there.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thank you for the information! While I'm glad to hear you are close, I'm afraid I'm still in the same position. It's a PCI compliance issue with the server so my client is pressing me to get this done immediately.